# Can I file for unemployment due to Covid-19 start date push back?

Tags: new-job, start-date, covid-19

I accepted a new job and submitted  my offer letter. My last day at my old employer was Thursday March 12th. My start date for my new employer was set for Monday March 16. Everything with Covid-19 had begun to happen and on Friday March 13, my new employer called to tell me that at my start date would be pushed back until further notice due to COVID-19.

So here I am currently with no income. I have a pending start date with new employer but I’m not on their payroll. Am I eligible for unemployment? Can I file a claim? Can someone offer their guidance with my situation?

Comment: Please indicate your location.

Comment: Your country, please.

Comment: In my jurisdiction, the test is whether you are out of work due to no fault of your own and this is determined by the government. I would say that after your original start date, you are out of work due to no fault of your own. You must ask your original employer to re-hire you though, otherwise, it's your fault you're unemployed.

Comment: [I downvoted because being unresponsive to requests for clarification is not helpful.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive)

Comment: I am also in a very similar situation, but no one answers at the unemployment office, you can't wait on hold, the message says "call back" . All I can do is apply online, but I don't know if I'm eligible either. I guess I'll apply and all they can do is deny (that's not my preferred approach).

Comment: @EJoshuaSReinstatesMonica: What the heck is this website? Why would anyone create such a useless website?

Comment: @LindaEdmonds, Check out Erick Leong's latest answer. According to him, if you're in the US, you are eligible under the CARE act.

Comment: You can use the [Contact Us](/contact) form to have your accounts merged, so that you can edit your question.

Answer (score 7):

You might be out of luck because you voluntarily quit your prior job, but the person you should be asking is the unemployment office for your area. Anyone on here is just giving an educated guess.

Comment: You'd better read their web site; most unemployment offices telephone lines are completely slammed these days.

Answer (score 6):

> Am I eligible for unemployment? Can I file a claim? Can someone offer
>   their guidance with my situation?

Call your state's unemployment office.

Only they can determine your eligibility.

Answer (score 3):

CARES act covers pushed start dates.

CARES Section 2102 (a)(3)(A)(ii)(I)(gg) adds a covered group under the Pandemic Unemployment Assistance to cover "the individual was scheduled to commence employment and does not have a job or is unable to reach the job as a direct result of the COVID-19 public health emergency."

You may not be eligible through normal means for Unemployment but the CARES act would apply. Good luck!

Comment: Erick, You may want to post your answer on this thread as well: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/157611/can-i-file-for-unemployment-if-my-new-employer-tries-to-change-my-already-signed Since Jamie hasn't said which country she's located in, I think the other question is more likely to become the primary question that others link to.

Comment: What might "CARES" be? Could you explain more?

Comment: CARES is HR 748-33 Coronavirus, Relief, and Economic Security Act passed in the US. You are correct in that I made an assumption about the authors country. Thanks for the feedback and I'll try and find similar threads.

Answer (score -2):

Again, this is something you can only find out by calling your unemployment office. If it turns out you are not currently eligible, it might be worth finding out if your new employer can help out by hiring you, paying you for a day or so, and then laying you off for the duration of the COVID-19 emergency.

Comment: But try to look on the office's website first. Calling now may take a long time to get an answer.