# New Joining delayed due to COVID-19

Tags: communication, recruitment, india, company-policy, covid-19

I was offered a new job before the virus outbreak. They had emailed me the offer letter and had promised to sent the contract early this week. They were also pushing me to join as quickly as possible.
So, I'd put my notice to my current employer on 25th Jan 2020 and told them to relieve me on or before 31st Mar. They tried to continue me with my current salary initially but I denied. But due to this situation, my new company informed me on 26th March that they hold new joining till 15th April 2020. I requested to my current employer to hold the notice period till 15th Apr but they was not agreed and I got relieved on 31st Mar 2020. I also requested to new company to join me online at least but they told this is not possible till the office opens.
Now, a days nothing on hand and simply seating at home. Hope the Lockdown will finish by 15th April and will be able to join. If not I will be in big trouble. 
Please suggest what can I do in this situation?

Comment: What is your goal? Probably you can do nothing but sit at home. What is your country and why don't you state it? Have you done all the things like clean your home, the windows, watch television shows etc.?

Comment: Pune,  Maharashtra,  India

Comment: Okay, and what is your goal?

Comment: Check the other questions that ask the same thing.

Comment: Did they state a start date in the offer letter? Do you have written communication of the start date being discussed? As a tip for future, never give your prior notice before discussing the start date and informing your new company you are giving prior notice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New employer postponing my start date due to COVID-19, what should I do?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/156722/new-employer-postponing-my-start-date-due-to-covid-19-what-should-i-do)

Comment: Yes..  I have taken in written on mail.  They mentioned that you can join from 15th Apr-2020. Also in offer letter the joining date mentioned is on or before 26th April 2020

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hope the Lockdown will finish by 15th April and will be able to join. If not I will be in big trouble. Please suggest what can I do in this situation?

I'm almost 100% sure that the lockdown will not be finished by the 15th of April so what I suggest you do in this situation is try to find a way to make some supplemental income by working from home. I will let you google that, if you don't I think you might find yourself in "big trouble".

Comment: Thanks and Yess..  please let me know if any..  I would like to do anything from home...